# Why my laravel routes tutorial is not working?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I m noob at php based web development, I'm trying a Laravel from scratch tutorial.

First I had an issue with the `.dev` that I fixed in laragon preferences using a `.mc` that will not forces https.

My link is http://localhost/e-commerce-tutorial/public/ for the welcome page

Now I m trying to create a routing scenario

I did put an `about.blade.php` page in : `resources/views/pages`

Then I edited the laravel wellcome page adding this link to the menu :

```
           <a href="{{ url('/about') }}">About</a>
```

finally my web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::any(
        '/about', 
        function (){
            return view('pages.about');
        }
 );
```

I did some research but no success:

I tried this two .htaccess

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

OR

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews -Indexes
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On

        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

My browser response is :

> Not Found The requested URL /e-commerce-tutorial/public/about was not
>
> found on this server.

Comment: which url you are hitting?

Comment: the one mentioned the about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>


    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /~projectname/master/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Also Please try this

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('pages.about');
});

Route::post('/about', function () {
    return view('pages.about');
});
```

Comment: not working :( what did you tried here please, some explanation even if it not solving

Comment: comment Route::any( line